# Representing two columns of data into a table

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have two columns of data as shown below.

```
   A     B
1 John   red 
2 John   yellow
3 John   yellow
4 Albert blue
5 Albert orange
6 Chad   blue
7 Tim    yellow
```

I would like to represent them in a grid/table format as shown:

```
   A      B     C       D     E          
1         red   yellow  blue  orange  
2 John    1     2       0     0
3 Albert  0     0       1     1
4 Chad    0     0       1     0
5 Tim     0     1       0     0
```

I am trying to represent the two columns in a table that keeps a count of the number of colours that each person is assigned to. I have successfully completed this by using array formula with countif and filling up the table using fill handling however was wondering if there was a more robust way of completing this task as my data can end up changing. i.e. using one formula in one cell to fill up the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**in google sheets**

This formula:

```
=QUERY(A1:C,"select A, Count(C) where A <>'' group by A pivot B")
```

or use only range `A1:B`, this formula:

```
=QUERY({A1:B,B1:B},"select Col1, Count(Col2) where Col1 <>'' group by Col1 pivot Col3")
```

---

To make formula show 0s instead of blanks, use this formula:

```
={{"";UNIQUE(A1:A8)},{TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B1:B8));ArrayFormula(MMULT(--(UNIQUE(A1:A8=transpose(A1:A8))),TRANSPOSE(--(UNIQUE(B1:B8)=TRANSPOSE(B1:B8)))))}}
```

if you want to use it with open ranges (`A1:A`, `B1:B`), then use this:

```
={{"";UNIQUE(OFFSET(A1,,,COUNTA(A1:A)))},{TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(OFFSET(B1,,,COUNTA(B1:B))));ArrayFormula(MMULT(--(UNIQUE(OFFSET(A1,,,COUNTA(A1:A))=transpose(OFFSET(A1,,,COUNTA(A1:A))))),TRANSPOSE(--(UNIQUE(OFFSET(B1,,,COUNTA(B1:B)))=TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(B1,,,COUNTA(B1:B)))))))}}
```

This formula is harder and it works slower, but you have more control on the result.

Comment: thanks! this works but it is leaving blanks instead of 0s. is there a way to replace all the blanks with zeros in the one formula

Comment: It's possible, but not so easy, because `Query` makes blanks automatically. One way is to use big formula, I'll edit the answer.